# get value of key embedded in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting this jSON as a response from an API I am using, how, in javascript, can I retrieve the value of the "intent" key.

I tried to retrieve it using ["outcomes"]["intent"], but I am getting an error saying there is not "outcomes" key.

```
{
  "msg_id": "0df2d41d-7468-4752-a5dc-5980e880aa7a",
  "_text": "i am feelig quite anxious because of school",
  "outcomes": [
    {
      "_text": "i am feelig quite anxious because of school",
      "intent": "more_negative",
      "entities": {},
      "confidence": 0.515
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `outcomes` is an **array** (with one element).

Comment: @FelixKling so json["outcomes"][0]["intent"]?

Comment: Assuming `json` contains the JS object corresponding to the JSON above, yes.